# inserting returned int from atoi() into array

Tags: c, arrays, atoi

I have a token from `strtok()` that I want to convert into and integer and place inside of an array using `atoi()`. However, I'm having difficulties.

```
char string[LMAX];
int array[LMAX];
int number;
char *token = NULL;
int count = 0;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("test.txt","r");

while(fgets (string, LMAX, fp) != NULL) { 
   //Reading the file, line by line
   printf("%s", string);
   token = strtok(string,",");
   array[count++] = atoi(token);
   //printf("%d",array[count]);
   while(token=strtok(NULL,";,")){
   number = atoi(token);
   array[count++] = number;
   printf("%d",array[count++]);
   } 

}
```

`number` is of type `int` and the array is initialised as an `int` array too.

When I run the following code, I get all 0's printed out, but the interesting thing is, when I replace `printf("%d", number);` with `printf("%d", atoi(token));`, I get the right output. I want to be able to actually store atoi(token) but it is not allowing me to.

Any help is great

EDIT: `LMAX = 1024`

Comment: `count` in uninitialized ?

Comment: Please post your complete code. The error is outside the three lines that you posted.

Comment: what the datatype of number variable.

Comment: "number" is of type int

Comment: Something wrong with your array declaration. Show the code...

Comment: This problem cannot be reproduced with this exact code ([link to a demo](http://ideone.com/u0EXrw)).

Comment: does count ever get larger than LMAX? there is nothing in the code to prevent it from doing so if the file is large enough

Comment: array[count] = atoi(token); should be array[count++] = atoi(token); ?

Comment: have edited the OP. @dasblinkenlight when I try and print the variable `number` I have no issues. It's only when I put `array[count++] in the printf statement that it gives me 0's in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's only when I put `array[count++]` in the printf statement that it gives me 0's in the output

This is because `count++` has side effects. When you assign `array[count++]` and then print `array[count++]`, you are not printing the same value, because the second time around the index is incremented.

Moreover, count will be incremented twice, so every other value in the `array` would be uninitialized.

If you want to print the value that you have just stored in the array, use `count-1` for the index:

```
while(token=strtok(NULL,";,")){
    number = atoi(token);
    array[count++] = number;
    printf("%d",array[count-1]);
}
```

Comment: same problem persists if I print `array[count]` after assigning `array[count++]`

Answer (score 0):

the printf statement is using a value of 'count' that is already incremented past the place in array where the value was placed.

this following pair of lines is even worse because

1) the count is incremented past where the value was placed
2) the count is incremented again in the printf statement

```
array[count++] = number;
printf("%d",array[count++]);
```

suggest only increment count once, at the end of the loop

the returned value from fopen should be check for != NULL to assure the operation was successful, and if not successful, call perror() then exit()

this loop:

```
while(fgets (string, LMAX, fp) != NULL) { 
   //Reading the file, line by line
   printf("%s", string);
   token = strtok(string,",");
   array[count++] = atoi(token);
   //printf("%d",array[count]);
   while(token=strtok(NULL,";,")){
   number = atoi(token);
   array[count++] = number;
   printf("%d",array[count++]);
   } 

}
```

has several problems, suggest:

```
while(fgets (string, LMAX, fp)) 
{ 
   //Reading/echoing the file, line by line
   printf("%s", string);

   token = strtok(string,",");

   while(token)
   {
       number = atoi(token);
       array[count] = number;
       printf("%d",array[count++]);
       token =strtok(NULL,";,"));
   } 
}
```

even these changes still need to have a check for the array[] being full added.